# HttpPost not persisting data in repository after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to implement a simple guest registration system. I want to redirect to my guest list after registering. However, the data from registration is not persisting. I currently am using a "hard-coded" database, as I am new to MVC. My database is stored in a repository class.

GuestsRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TablePlanningApp.Models;

namespace TablePlanningApp.Data
{
    public class GuestsRepository
    {
        public List<Guest> _guests { get; set; }

        public GuestsRepository()
        {
            _guests = new List<Guest>();

        }

        public List<Guest> GetGuests()
        {
            return _guests;
        }

        public void AddGuest(Guest guest)
        {
            _guests.Add(guest);
        }
    }
}
```

GuestsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TablePlanningApp.Models;
using TablePlanningApp.Data;

namespace TablePlanningApp.Controllers
{
    public class GuestsController : Controller
    {

        private readonly GuestsRepository _guestsRepository = null;

        public GuestsController()
        {
            _guestsRepository = new GuestsRepository();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var guests = _guestsRepository.GetGuests();

            return View(guests);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddGuest()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddGuest(Guest guest)
        {
            _guestsRepository.AddGuest(guest);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

AddGuest.cshtml

```
@model TablePlanningApp.Models.Guest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register Guest";
}

<h2>Register Guest</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Your Name")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Guest Name" })
        <small id="note" class="form-text text-muted">RSVP for accompanying guests below. Do not need to enter accompanying guests' name.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Contact, "Your Contact Number")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your contact" })

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsVegetarian) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsVegetarian, true)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsHalal) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsHalal, true)
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

I expected any guest to be populated after I click the submit button, but the list was still empty after submission. Appreciate any assistance, thank you!

Comment: You get a new controller instance for every request, which means your repo is `new`ed up every request, which in turn resets your list of guests, that's why you're losing your info.

Comment: Johan is correct. If you don't want to lose data you need to code your repository to actually store it somewhere, be that in a file or a database. Although you _could_ also utilize dependency injection and make it a scoped or a singleton service (if your DI library supports it).